# Round Corners for Gmail Newsletter

Tags: css, gmail

i am trying to apply a rounded corner style for a newsletter i made, when i open the file locally everything seems fine, but when sent to a gmail account, it will strip some codes and wont read some inline css properties.

So my question is, if there is a way to create round corner, while not making it look bad for the other mail clients.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is less supported in email newsletters. It is better to use image slices for the best results.

---

**More Description:**

Round corners, gradients, backgrounds, You can't embed these objects in newsletters using CSS. You must create slices for Round corners, gradients and backgrounds to use them in your newsletter by embedding with `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Tumay http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - There is also other content that is very helpful for designing emails.http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/ -- Also Mailchimp has good resources http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/